# ESRI Javascript API - Emulate 'Red Glow' Effect From Flex API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to emulate the red glow effect so common in the Flex API Examples.  Really, any type of blinking/flashing style marker will do.  I am assuming I will have to use a picture marker symbol with an animated gif?

I have probably infected my computer with who knows what downloading trial software to convert from swf to gif and all types of other non nonsensical conversions.  I am hoping someone can point me to an example or give me some insight on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Found what I was looking for in one of the [JSAPI demos](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/exp_geolocate.html).

Comment: Glad you found the link to that sample, that's what I would have suggested. I would use that effect sparingly, though. Animation for animation's sake is rarely a good idea. It's a novel effect initially, but if your app will have lots of repeat users, the animation will likely become more of an annoyance to them over time.

Comment: I also agree it is a novel effect initially. In my applications I find that setting the -animation-iteration-count to 2 or 3 provides the ability to grab the users attention and still not become an annoyance. It is experimental and not completely supported (IE10?) but thats fine for most of my users.

Comment: @theJones– good call, more on -animation-iteration-count:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/animation-iteration-count